# Clarification of a C.D.F. $P(\frac {(X-µ)^2} {\sigma^2} < 2.706)$ for a normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable with a normal distribution such that $E(X) =
µ$ and $Var(X) = σ^2$

From my understanding I can write the p.d.f. of a normal distribution as

$f(x) = \frac {e^{ \frac {-(x-µ)^2} {2 \sigma^2}}} {\sigma \sqrt {2\pi}}$ 
,or equivalently (?) $f(w) = \frac {e^{\frac{-w}{2}}} {\sigma \sqrt {2\pi}}$ where
$w= \frac {-(x-µ)^2} {\sigma^2}$

A question in my probability textbook arises to compute 
$P(\frac {(X-µ)^2} {\sigma^2} < 2.706)$ . Is this equivalent to asking when $P(W<2.706)$ i.e. the integral $\int_{- \infty}^{2.706} \frac {e^{\frac{-w}{2}}} {\sigma \sqrt {2\pi}} dw$ or perhaps I am confused. Any insights or clarifications much appreciated.

Comment: This is rather $$\int_{- \sqrt{2.706}}^{\sqrt{2.706}} \frac {e^{-t^2/2}} { \sqrt {2\pi}} dt=\int_{0}^{2.706} \frac {e^{-w/2}} { \sqrt {2\pi w}} dw$$